# How to solve one sided limits in one given graph?

Tags: calculus

[image]Thanks a lot! My first thread about one sided limits got great and quick responses. Now I would need help to correct my answers please.I made the exercises and am not sure if they are correct so please if you find any mistakes let me know.
[image]

Comment: What is your question?  Please type it, don't just post images.  Also, from what I can make out in the image, this question appears to have nothing at all to do with linear algebra or algebraic graph theory.

Comment: Sorry I was in a hurry and my question is if someone can correct it which I already stated

Comment: I can't even read it.

Comment: I edited it now. Hope you can read it better.

Comment: You have made many mistakes here.

Comment: Can you say what exactly is wrong ?

Comment: An open circle is a hole in the graph.  A closed (filled) circle is a point on the graph, so $f(-2)$ is undefined (as no value has been assigned to it), while $f(3) = -1$.

Comment: Thank you, I didn’t know that so. F(4) would be 1 as well?

Comment: And what about the limits? Are they correct?

Comment: You are correct that $f(4) = 1$.  There are errors among your limit calculations as well.

Comment: Hm could you be more specific please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think rather than go through and correct your mistakes, I will try to explain how to solve these problems in general.

Lets go over how to read the diagram.  An *open* circle denotes a 'hole' in the function.  Let's look at the circle at $(3,-2)$.  This circle means that the function is defined by the horizontal line (that goes from $(1,-2)$ to $(3,-2)$) for $x$ values that are really close to $3$, but not at $3$ itself.  Specifically, $f(2.9)=f(2.99)=f(2.999)=\cdots=-2$, but $f(3)\neq -2$.  On the other side of the hole, we see that the function is defined by the diagonal line (going to $(4,1)$).  This means that $f(3.1)$ is defined by that line, as is $f(3.01),f(3.001),f(3.0001),\cdots$, but *not* $f(3)$ itself.

A *closed* circle is defining the function at a particular point.  Let's look at the circle at $(3,-1)$.  This means that the function at $x=3$ is equal to $-1$, ie $f(3)=-1$.  This closed circle can be seen as 'filling in' the hole left by the circle at $(3,-2)$.

Now lets (informally) define a limit.  Consider an example:

$$\lim_{x\to {-2}^{-}} f(x)$$

This asks us to look at $f(x)$ for values of $x$ which are slightly less than $-2$, and see what happens when $x$ gets closer and closer to $-2$.  In the diagram, we see that when $x<-2$, there is a diagonal line that defines $f(x)$.  We see that if we start from $x=-3$ and get *really close* to $x=-2$ the $y$ value gets really close to $2$.  Thus $\lim_{x\to -2^{-}}f(x)=2$.

Now

$$\lim_{x\to {-2}^{+}} f(x)$$

asks us something similar, but now we start with $x$ values slightly *more* than $-2$.  We see that there is a different diagonal line that defines the function now.  If we start from $x=-1$ and decrease $x$ getting closer to $x=-2$, we see that the line's $y$ value gets close to $6$. Thus $\lim_{x\to {-2}^{+}} f(x)=6$.

Finally,

$$\lim_{x\to {-2}} f(x)$$

is defined *if and only if* $\lim_{x\to {-2}^{+}} f(x)=\lim_{x\to {-2}^-} f(x)$.  In this case, $\lim_{x\to {-2}} f(x)=\lim_{x\to {-2}^{+}} f(x)=\lim_{x\to {-2}^-} f(x)$.

Comment: Thank you that was very well written and easy to understand.  I understood everything except the last sentence, which confused me a bit My question is what limx→−2 f(x) would be?

Comment: The limit is only defined if $\lim_{x\to 2^-}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 2^+}f(x)$.  Since the left hand side is $2$, but the right hand side is $6$, the limit does not exist.

Comment: If the one-sided limits exist and agree, then the two-sided limit exists and is equal to the one-sided limit. Think about it in a picture.

Comment: I posted an update it’s the upper picture. I understand concept but have difficulties applying them. Please correct if you have the time

Comment: On number 4, $\lim_{x\to 4^-}f(x)=1$, but $\lim_{x\to 4^+}f(x)=2$.  What does that mean about $\lim_{x\to 4}f(x)$?